# Bulk upload into MySQL using Node.js Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, csv, express

I want an Node.js application which uploads some csv file e.g. Employee.csv and dumps employee  data into MySQL database.

I was successfully in uploading the file to server but when I'm executing the query to bulk upload it cause 500 error, even I'm able to figure out the exact cause of the error.

```
app.post('/BulkEmployeeFile',function(req,res,next){

var fullpath = __dirname + "\\uploads\\" + filename;    
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" +fullpath+ "' INTO TABLE user FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;";

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err)
                console.log('Error while performing Query.');   
            else{   
                connection.release();
                res.redirect('/BulkEmployee?done=true');
            }
        });     
});  });
```

I suppose connection.query is not able to execute LOAD DATA INFILE.

Can any one help me how to accomplish bulk upload into MySQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the actual error `err` say?

Comment: Actually it doesn't show any error, I tried printing the err but nothing is shown

Comment: Well if there is no error... then the query executed successfully. Does the imported data show up in your table?

Comment: What is `filename`..? maybe it's undefined, hence throwing the error..? You should post relevant code and the exact error message